# form validation is not working in JavaScript multistep form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Validation is not working here , I am stuck here please help

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please, 1) avoid using images of your code (helpers should have the opportunity to easily copy/paste) 2) avoid  to say "not working" but to specify "what" doesn't work and what you expect 3) give those who should help you all the useful information to solve the problem: help us to help you.

Comment: You are saying `next_step == ""`, why do you expect that it would be a string ?

Comment: so what should I pass here?